# How to use SpeedFan or any other app to further cool down the CPU and GPU?

Tags: fan, speedfan

I installed the latest SpeedFan for my Dell Studio 15 Notebook, which after installing Windows 7 on it, may turn off by itself after some use.

SpeedFan used to not tell the speed of fan, until yesterday I checked the box in the Options that says: "check this box for Dell notebooks", and the fan's RPM is shown.

The temperature of the GPU, as well as one core was as high as 85, and sometimes drop to 80, but I am suspecting this may be the problem of the computer turning itself off.  I check the box "Automatically adjust fan speed" or uncheck it, and change the fan speed % to 100%, but the strange thing is, the fan may slow down after a bit, and when I change the 100% to 95%, I can hear the fan revving up -- to a higher RPM -- being more noisy as well (RPM now showing 5300 instead of 4200), but after some 30 seconds or a minute, it will slow down again, to being more quiet.  And after unknown time, the computer will turn off by itself.  I tried again using "Automatically adjust fan speed", but also after some unknown time, I come back to the computer and it is automatically turned off again (it is by powering off itself within a split second, instead of doing the proper shut up which can last 20 to 30 seconds).

Is 85 too hot for the GPU and the CPU?  Can't SpeedFan be adjusted so that it just make the fan go 100% all the time -- at least during this experiment -- so that the computer won't turn off by itself?

Comment: I'd also look into more practical approaches to this, e.g. making sure not placing the laptop on the bed, as it obstructs the airflow going in and out of the laptop.

Comment: I first placed it on a wooden desk, and it turned off by itself, so later on, i put DVD case underneath the left side and the right side of the base of the computer -- the support is only about 1 inch under the computer, so that more air can flow -- same thing: will turn off by itself.  And third, I put a metal wire magazine rack under the computer, hoping the metal can absorb the heat and disperse it out in the surrounding, but no help, still turn off.  The only way seems to be not run demanding apps on it, such as VLC or Hauppauge PVR video recording app.

Answer (score 1):

To allow SpeedFan to control completely, you Must turn off normal thermal controls first.  Usually this is done in the Bios, but it is not always capable of being turned off. Once the normal thermal controls are off the fans then got to 100% until the speedfan then begins to control them.

What you have going is 2 things trying to change the same parameters. In desktop bioses the controls are found in the monitoring sections, or the power sections, (not readily apparent) I dont know where it is in a notebook.

There are some instances where having "software" controlling is a disadvantage, like in standby situations, or if things crash.  Just so you know that it is not without possible ramifications.

Comment: since if I click on the up or down arrow to make it 95% or 100%, the fan rev'ed up to the max, so it looks like the program SpeedFan can actually rev up the fan to the max by itself, say, for example, every 10 or 20 seconds, send the signal to max the fan speed...  and in that case the BIOS can be treated as overridden?

Comment: yes keep sending out a repeated command, you would  still have some boucing around. I do not know if there are any things in speed fan to set that.